# (VB.NET) msgbox when focus is set on a text box

Tags: vb.net

How do I get a messagebox to appear if user clicks on a text box or tabs to it? I tried putting the messagebox on GotFocus and it just generates a new message box everytime i close the message box

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     TextBox1.GotFocus

    MsgBox(" ")
End Sub
```

Comment: show what you have .. hope we can help you

Comment: Why do you want this? Wouldn't a tooltip text be more useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Enter Instead...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
    MsgBox("Please Input A Text")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm... I was unable to test because I was reinstalling VS at the time so I assumed that `Enter` would behave the same way as `GotFocus`.  Just got to test and apparently not so +1.

Comment: GotFocus is like a toggle button that continuously execute the event.
Compare to Enter that will execute once, once the tool is selected.

Thanks for accepting my answer...